# Terminal Root Command Warning

Tags: terminal, root

Is it possible to write a script (or change some file) in order to warn the user that they are using a command that is normally reserved for root? And if so, how?

I'm currently the administrator of my machine, but I'd still like a warning that reminds me I'm using a root command.

Comment: Doesn't the password prompt tip them off?

Comment: Can you please give an example of "a command that is normally reserved for root"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean by "a command that is normally reserved for root"?

Generally everyone is able to run each command. However some commands need privileges only available to root. If you are not root, the command will usually tell you and refuse to do what you ask it to do.

Just normally work as a normal user and use something like `sudo` to explicitly use the power of root.

Some systems distinguish there command in "normal commands" and "system commands", and put them under `/bin` vs. `/sbin` or `/usr/bin` vs. `/usr/sbin`.
Usually the commands in `sbin` are usually more often used by root.

Is Debian the `sbin` directories default to be only in the `$PATH` of root. In Archlinux they are simply symlinks to the one directory containing all binaries.

Answer (score 1):

Being root all the time is the worst idea ever. Even if you are an admin. Be a regular user and switch to root when you reach a command that complains about root privileges. Use `sudo` or just plain old `su`. Otherwise you will sooner or later do something irreversible. Even if you are careful, it happens sometimes.

I don't think there is a clean way of doing this any other way. It strongly depends on what the program is doing, it's not the binary that can't be run (except for things in `sbin`), it's attempted changes that are stopped if you aren't allowed to do it. For instance: package manager (`pacman`/`apt`,...) may allow anyone to search for packages and query installed packages. It's when you want to install something (which writes in `/usr/bin`, `/lib/` and so on), that you get an error. Some other tools also check explicitly who you are and complain before attempting to do anything. A text editor, for example, will fail to write into `/etc/fstab` if you are not root, but by itself it's not a "root" command. And finally, you have those funny "sticky" commands that pretend you are someone else when they run (it runs as the owner of the binary, usually root -- `mount` does that).

Answer (score 0):

You can set your root's prompt differently

For instance, become root, edit (or create) /root/.bashrc and add:

```
export PS1="\[\033[0;31m\]\u\[\033[0m\]@\h:\w #"
```

explanation part by part:

```
\[\033[0;31m\] ansi code for red color to distinguish root 
\u             user name
\[\033[0m\]    ansi code to restore normal console color
@              typical separator between user and host
\h             current hostname 
:              separator between host and path
\w             current path
#              a final symbol other than the usual '$'
```

With this you would see:

```
root@my_host:/foo/bar #
```

With 'root' printed in red color, instead of the usual

```
your_name@my_host:/foo/bar $
```

If you want to know more read the PROMPTING section at the bash man pages